# Error found only in gcc-6.1.0 while parsing the arguements using va_arg()

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, variadic-functions

I find error saying " error: assignment to expression with array type " for my following piece of code compiled in gcc 6.1.0 but not in gcc 4.4.6.

```
void foo(char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int d;
    char *c, *s;
    typedef unsigned char mac_t[6];

    mac_t ad;   
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    while (*fmt)
    switch (*fmt++) {
    case 's':  
        s = va_arg(ap, char *);
        printf("string %s\n", s);
     break;
    case 'd':              /* int */
        d = va_arg(ap, int);
        printf("int %d\n", d);
    break;
    case 'c':              /* char */
        ad = va_arg(ap, mac_t);  //**** error here only on gcc 6.1.0 compiler 
        printf("With unsigned char: char %c.%c.%c.%c.%c.%c\n", ad[0],ad[1],ad[2],ad[3],ad[4],ad[5]);                                              
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
int main()
{
    foo("%c", "AABBCC");
}
```

How can I solve this error? In gcc 4.4.6, the compilation passes smoothly. For some reasons I need to use gcc 6.1.0 compiler only.

Comment: I did try strcpy(ad, va_arg(ap, mac_t));. It doesn't give me any compiler error. But it doesn't serve the purpose. I mean, the arguments are not copied to array ad. I see invalid data when I print the contents of ad.

Comment: Arrays decay to a pointer type when passed to a function. gcc 6.1.0 gets it right, you cannot assign to an array.

Comment: @jxh Exactly. strcpy() doesn't work on pointers. Any other way to parse the arguments in gcc 6.1.0?

Comment: @George But how do I use it with va_arg()? I want parse my arguments and store in ad array.

Comment: Just for clarity, what are you ultimately hoping will be in `ad[]` when this is finished? Is it the ascii values `0x41, 0x41, 0x42, 0x42, 0x43, 0x43` ? Or is it the octets from the hex chars, `0x10, 0x10, 0x11, 0x11, 0x12, 0x12` ?

Comment: I need hex characters. But how does that matter? can you please elaborate?

Comment: It matters because conversion to the latter sequence isn't hinted at in your posted code. At *best* the result will be the ascii chars from the input string to an `unsigned char` array with no translation to basic octets. If that's what you want, outstanding. If not, and indeed you simply want a six-octet mac you have a ways to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
typedef unsigned char mac_t[6];
mac_t ad;
```

And then you attempt:

```
ad = va_arg(ap, mac_t);
```

When, you have passed the argument like this:

```
foo("%c", "AABBCC");
```

This is an error. You cannot assign to an array. Also, `"AABBCC"` is an array [7] of char because of the NUL terminated string literal. However, that doesn't matter. `foo()` receives a `char *`, since an array type decays to the pointer containing the address of its first element.

You should be able to see the error if you pass `-std=c99` to GCC. Apparently, this enables more strict checking.

```
gcc -std=c99 -W -Wall -O c.c
c.c: In function ‘foo’:
c.c:25:12: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘mac_t’ from type ‘unsigned char *’
         ad = va_arg(ap, mac_t);  // error here only on gcc 6.1.0 compiler
            ^
```

To fix this, tell `va_arg` you are parsing a pointer. If you must copy the contents, then use `strncpy`.

```
strncpy((void *)ad, va_arg(ap, char *), sizeof(ad));
```

We coerce `ad`, because `strncpy` expects a `char *` as the first argument.